# Solr 6.2.0 sending boolean values as false always

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to use solrj client with solr version 6.2.0 and it seems it is sending false values always even if the actual value is true

I tried to get value using solr web query there the values are right but its just solrj client which is getting wrong values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using solr version 6.2.1 as it seems to be bug with version 6.2.0

They have reported it on link
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9490

hope it helps!